Kentico 9 google recaptcha issue
While using google recaptcha in kentico 9 I am getting the below error in event log. But there is no such file in the the path given. In another server the captcha is sometimes working sometimes not. Can anyone provide some solution to this.
Message: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive.
Exception type: System.Net.WebException
Stack Trace:
at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
at CMS.UIControls.NewRecaptchaValidator.Validate() in C:\Working\TrisetWeb\Kentico v9.0.50\NewReCaptcha\NewRecaptchaValidator.cs:line 133
Message: The client and server cannot communicate, because they do not possess a common algorithm
Solution to above question.

Isn't it possible that this was added by some marketplace module? If I remember correctly, there was a package available on the old marketplace which added the new reCAPTCHA from Google to some old Kentico versions.

@jurajo Yes I import the form control from a running kentico 9. In that site it is running perfectly but current site is showing the above error which I have shared already

How did you exported it? Were the physical code files included in the export? have you tried copying the file from the working env. to this one?

While exporting I had marked to include the physical file apart from that I have cross checked the physical file the content are same.
this is the site https://williambonnici.wodongafn.com.au/contact
I dont find any error in the console also

What check box was checked? Physical files could be related to media files or page attachments. Or, did you meant the code files check box?

I mean code files

Ok, so these seem to be OK. Have you tried searching on Google for the "The client and server cannot communicate, because they do not possess a common algorithm" error? Maybe you may need to update some target framework or TLS or other security settings. It does not seem to be a Kentico related issue.

Can you provide more information about your project's set up?  Is it a Web Application or a Website?  If the error is pointing to a file that does not exist then you need to add/include that project in to your current project.
If I remember this correctly, there was a separate project that was included in the CMS project.  I'd highly recommend going to the project you exported this out of and reviewing the file system.  You should find a folder named "NewReCaptcha".  In there you should find 3 files:

NewRecaptchaControl.cs
NewRecaptchaResponse.cs
NewRecaptchaValidator.cs

You need to migrate these 3 files over to your new project and update the namespaces.  Then in your control, likely located here: /CMS/FormControls/Recaptcha/NewRecaptcha...
You need to update references to those classes in the form control.
If the form control was not set up to be exported and imported then it won't properly work and you'll have to manually copy files like I've mentioned above.

This is a website. In one of the kentico 9 website where it is running successfully I don't find any file called NewRecaptchaValidator.cs.
There are two files NewRecaptcha.ascx.cs, NewRecaptcha and two dlls NewRecaptcha.dll,NewRecaptcha.pdb

Then those 3 files I mentioned are compiled into that NewRecaptcha.dll file.  At one time, those files had to be part of one of your projects to be included like they were.

the files are there. But unable to track why event log is giving the error    Message: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive.
Exception type: System.Net.WebException
Stack Trace:
at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
at CMS.UIControls.NewRecaptchaValidator.Validate() in C:\Working\TrisetWeb\Kentico v9.0.50\NewReCaptcha\NewRecaptchaValidator.cs:line 133
Message: The client and server cannot communicate, because they do not possess a common algorithm
